# Who are the founders of EOS and are any of them anonymous like satoshi?

Tags: eosio-code

Was EOS created by 1 person or a team of people and are they all public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Was EOS created by 1 person or a team of people and are they all public?

The EOS community blockchain was launched by a team of block producers and contributors, and most have some sorts of known public identity. However, the software that was used to launch the blockchain (EOSIO) was developed by a company called Block.one.

---

If it helps, here's a cheatsheet

## What's EOS?

- A public community-led blockchain (also called EOS mainnet)
- The native token of the EOS mainnet
- Confusingly, it's also the name of the repository that hosts the EOSIO software

## What's EOSIO?

The software that can launch eosio-based blockchains. At the moment, the most popular such blockchain is the EOS mainnet, but several others (public and private) are planned to or have already launched as well.

This website is about EOSIO.

## What's Block.one?

Block.one is the company that developed and maintains the EOSIO software, but they haven't launched any public blockchain themselves. They're working on improving the software to help both public chains and private chains alike.

---

For a more detailed explanation, please see the [FAQ on EOS.io](https://eos.io/faq)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily find lots of EOS facts on Google.

Here same easy intro to EOS:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EOS.IO

Anyway yes, EOS it is definetely public, Brendan Blumer is the CEO and Dan Larimer is the CTO.